# FragmentActivity disappears when back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I have a FragmentActivity with a ViewPager holding 3 Fragments. When I start a new FragmentActivity from within one of the fragments inside the ViewPager, I can not return to the FragmentActivity with the ViewPager at all.

So here is what happens:

#### FragmentActivity1 -> (via Intent) FragmentActivity2 -> (via Intent) FragmentActiviy3

when pressing back, FragmentActivity1 is shown and not FragmentActivity2 as expected. The only difference between the FragmentActivityes is that FragmentActivity2 holds a ViewPager with fragments.

**SOLUTION:** I was calling at some other point an activity.finish(), which caused FragmentActivity2 to destroy itself when pausing

**EDIT: yet onDestroy() is called after I called FragmentActivity3!**

**EDIT 2:**
    Logcat of the flow what happens

```
01-15 15:04:43.356: D/FrgmentActivity2(2919): FrgmentActivity2 onStart()
01-15 15:04:43.356: D/On resume(2919): FrgmentActivity2 onResume()
01-15 15:04:48.496: D/Intent(2919): FrgmentActivity2 starting FrgmentActivity3 activity
01-15 15:04:48.816: D/FrgmentActivity2(2919): FrgmentActivity2 onStop()
01-15 15:04:48.816: D/FrgmentActivity2(2919): FrgmentActivity2 onDestroy()
```

The activity is defenitely being destroyed, but I have no clue why.

**EDIT 3**:
    How I am calling the new activity (no finish() call anywhere)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, FrgmentActivity3.class);
activity.startActivity(intent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
Log.d("Intent", "FrgmentActivity2 starting FrgmentActivity3 activity");
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you supplying any flags when executing the intent e.g. FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY (this flag can also be defined in the activity element in your Android manifest)

Comment: @Damian Hi Damian, thanks for the hint. No, I'm not adding any flags to the Intent call. What I also did figure out is that the onDestroy() method is being called in FragmentActivity2, when I call the FragmentActivity3 via Intent.

Comment: Override onDestroy() and onStop() functions of FragmentActivity2 and display the logs. like public void onDestroy(){ super.onDestroy(); Log.i("Activity2", "Destroying")},  check the output to confirm that is FragmentActivity2 destroying on opening 3rd Activity OR it just not including in Activity hierarchy!

Comment: @AhmadRaza Hi Ahmed, I included the log in under EDIT 2. It is obvious that the FragmentActivity2 is being destroyed, but why? I see no reason why this should happen.

Comment: without any code for how you are loading the new FragmentActivity I can only guess....are you calling finish(), this can kill the activtiy.

Comment: @PhilH Good point, I just got the thing working with your help. It was a .finish() call inside a pause statement... That is why the onDestroy() statement got called. Thanks for the hint!